# Jasmine + test external dependency

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

I was wondering the best way to use jasmine to test external dependencies.

For example I have an overlay  module that purely shows and hides a background mask:

```
function Overlay () {

}

Overlay.prototype.show = function () {

}

Overlay.prototype.hide = function () {

}
```

This has complete Jasmine unit tests set up.

I then have another module Dialog that uses the overlay Module:

```
function Dialog () {

}

Dialog.prototype.show() {
 //do dialog stuff here, then show overlay
 var overlay = new Overlay();
 overlay.show();
}
```

I have Jasmine tests that test all the dialog apart from the overlay. With the assumption that the overlay unit tests are setup and passing does the dialog test just need to ensure that var overlay is defined and that its show method has been called?

For separation of concerns is this the best way to do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Best way would be to inject an instance of your overlay into the constructor of your Dialog.

```
function Dialog (overlay) {
  this.overlay = overlay:
}

Dialog.prototype.show() {
 this.overlay.show();
}
```

In your test you can then simply inject a spy.

```
var overlay = {show: jasmine.createSpy()};
var dialog = new Dialog(overlay);
dialog.show();
expect(overlay.show). toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Another way would be to spy on the global `Overlay` function and return a object with spy on the `show` function.

```
var overlay = {show: jasmine.createSpy()};
jasmine.spyOn(Overlay, 'show').andReturn(overlay);
var dialog = new Dialog(overlay);
dialog.show();
expect(overlay.show). toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Comment: that makes sense, but what about when my dialog is being used in a further module, overlay would then have to be injected into two levels. e.g.anotherModule(dialog, overlay), dialog(overlay) etc... This is why I call new Overlay() in my dialog script, but can this way be properly testable?

Comment: Its explained in the second example